# looking for a combinatorial approach rather thanthe conditional probability approach

Tags: combinatorics, conditional-probability

bowler has taken  5 five-wicket hauls in his last 17 matches. His match records are selected at random, one by one, and analyzed. If none of the match records is analyzed more than once, then what is the probability that the 11th one analyzed is his  last five-wicket haul match?
term ---a five wicket haul is a match in which a player took 5 wickets

so i am looking for way to calculate the probability using just combinations,i.e. is not including the notion of conditional probability

I've come up with  (12C6 x 5C4)/17C10

but the answer is (12C6 x 5C4)/(17C10*7)

Comment: As an aside... I would not consider either answer to be using a "*conditional probability approach*"... this is not a conditional probability question.  The "*if none of the match records is analyzed more than once*" is not a condition so much as it is a clarification.

Comment: Strange wording, but from the answers, it seems you want all five special matches in the first eleven but not the first ten.  So I would say the answer was $\frac{{11 \choose 5}-{10 \choose 5}}{17 \choose 5}$

Comment: As an aside, Henry's answer is the same as mine and the books, noting Pascal's identity that $\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{5}=\binom{11}{5}$.  There are often many ways of correctly phrasing the correct answer.  The point is to adequately describe the scenario.  Heck, you could do this with the entire order mattering and using the full $17!$ arrangements of the matches for your denominator if you wanted... giving $\frac{\binom{10}{4}\cdot 5!\cdot 12!}{17!}$ as the answer which you will find equals the rest.  I dislike that presentation however, finding it tedious and inelegant.

Comment: @JMoravitz In defense of the title, some people might take an approach that first computes the probability of four of the five-wicket hauls occurring in the first ten matches, and then the conditional probability of the eleventh match being the fifth five-wicket haul, given that four of the five-wicket hauls occurred in the first ten matches. The symbolic form of the answer could then be practically identical to the book's answer (just multiply by $\frac17$ instead of putting the factor $7$ in the denominator) but the approach still has a different flavor.

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, I will refer to the "five-wicket hauls" as outcomes labeled $A$ and the remaining games as outcomes labeled $B$

There are $\binom{17}{5}$ ways to pick the order of $A$'s and $B$'s such that there are five $A$'s and twelve $B$'s.  Each of these orders of $A$'s and $B$'s are equally likely to have occurred when ordering and analyzing the match records.

Of these, $\binom{10}{4}$ of these are ways in which four of the $A$'s occur within the first ten spots and the fifth occurring on the $11$'th position.

The probability is then:

$$\frac{\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{17}{5}}=\frac{15}{442}\approx 0.03393665\dots$$

---

Now, comparing to yours and the book's answer... we see they both treated each match still as distinct without making the same simplification that I had.  The numerators both suggest that we are trying to piece together what the first ten matches looked like.  Both correctly count this as $\binom{12}{6}\binom{5}{4}$ ways to have picked six "B" type games and four "A" games (*but keeping their specific match details distinct*).

That is all well and good talking about the first ten matches, but we are talking about the first *eleven* matches.  The eleventh match is going to be the remaining "$A$" game.  Now, the denominator... in your answer was just talking about the number of ways the first ten matches could have been collectively selected.

Again... we are supposed to have been talking about the number of ways the first *eleven* matches were selected with special emphasis on which of those eleven selected happened to be the eleventh match.

The book's answer does this correctly by first picking the first ten matches in $\binom{17}{10}$ ways *and then picking the eleventh match out of the seven remaining matches available* in $7$ ways for a total of $\binom{17}{10}\cdot 7$.  You could also have done this by picking the eleven matches and picking one from that in $\binom{17}{11}\cdot 11$ or by picking the eleventh match first and then picking the ten after in $17\cdot \binom{16}{10}$...  there are several equally correct ways to do this... but in each we still remembered to keep track of the eleventh match somehow which your answer failed to do.